# myLooper() does not quit during Asynchronous task

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I understand I may be doing this a bit backwards, but haven't found a suitable solution yet and this is the closest I have come. I am first presenting a Login view to the user and submitting the inputted credentials to a web service which validates credentials and returns a HTTP 200 if the logon was successful. Upon success, I am then making a HTTP JSON request to the same web service to download a list of JSON objects. These objects are then parsed, and placed into a SQLite DB. There are around 100 or more objects, so an async task is appealing so I don't lock up the UI. The point of this is to display a ProgressBar (indeterminate) to the user saying there is work being done in the background, then return them to a separate Intent once the DB is populated. Here is the code snippets:

**Validating the login and calling the login action:**

```
switch(statusCode) {
   case 200:
      PrepareLogin doLogin = new PrepareLogin();
      doLogin.execute();
      if (doLogin.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
         // Redirect to intent?
      }
      break;
   case 401:
      Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Async task with helper functions in the background:**

```
private class PrepareLogin extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.get_login_dialog_title));
            dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_login_dialog_message));
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Looper.myLooper().prepare();
            Looper.myLooper().loop();
            DBHelper dbHelp = new DBHelper(Login.this);
            WSHelper wsHelp = new WSHelper();
            long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
            dbHelp.resetDB(Login.this); // For dev environment only...remove in prod
            dbHelp.create();
            dbHelp.createUser(username, password, timeNow, "false");
            dbHelp.close();
            wsHelp.getEmployees(Login.this, username, password);
            Looper.myLooper().quit();
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute() {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(login.getContext(), Main.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

The only way I can get this to function without throwing the "Handler must prepare a looper" error, is with the `Looper.myLooper.prepare()` function.

I can see in the logs that the connection is made and DB populated, but the dialog continues to spin and it never reaches the `onPostExecute()` function of the Async task. It hits the `Looper.myLooper().quit();` line though.

Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0):

If you get "Handler must prepare a looper" error, most probably you are calling the AsyncTask in a wrong context. I don't remember I ever need to explicitly call `Looper.prepare()` function in any AsyncTask. Once you get rid of the looper, it would be fine, the AsyncTask is one of the easiest to use class in Android. You should post your code in the Login class (I suppose it is an Activity, right?).

Another problem I can find is:

```
case 200:
        PrepareLogin doLogin = new PrepareLogin();
        doLogin.execute();
        if (doLogin.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
             // Redirect to intent?
        }
break;
```

Your `doLogin.execute();` should not be a blocking call, so the next `if` is guaranteed to be wrong, so the redirect would never fire.

Comment: This is actually already in the Login class, I apologize, should have specified. What I believe is happening is when it is calling my helper classes to get the JSON data and iterate over it, inserting into the database, it stops on the first or second entry in the DB. I've thoroughly tested my helper class to ensure it is working just fine, seeing as the database is populated properly without this AsyncTask.

Comment: Could it also be that one of my helpers is creating a separate thread outside of the current AsyncTask? Does that make sense? Because when I comment the `Looper.myLooper()` functions out, it fails with `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my WSHelper class was attempting to making some sort of change to the UI from the background process. By removing the wsHelp initialization from the AsyncTask and making it a constant, I was able to proceed just fine. It may also be worth noting I changed the return value to void for the wsHelp.getEmployees() method.